# My array isn't generated correctly in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with my array. Somehow it doesn't understand where my array is. I tried with the following code:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {              
    $pers_inventar = array();

    $pers_id = $row['pers_id'];
    $pers_person = array('birthday' => $row['pers_birthday'],'lastname' => $row['pers_lastname'],'firstname' => $row['pers_firstname'],'job' => $row['pers_job']);
    $pers_inventar[$pers_id][] = $pers_person;
}
```

Maybe my function is wrong. Thanks for any help

Comment: Remove `$pers_inventar = array();` from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
$pers_inventar = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {              
              $pers_id = $row['pers_id'];
              $pers_person = array('birthday' => $row['pers_birthday'],'lastname' => $row['pers_lastname'],'firstname' => $row['pers_firstname'],'job' => $row['pers_job']);
              $pers_inventar[$pers_id][] = $pers_person;
        }
```

The best is, when you add an empty array first and then go into your while loop.

Another suggestion:

Why do you create an array to put in your "pers_id" array?
Why don't you just create your "pers_id" array and add the information right in there.

Comment: That worked perfectly. And thanks for the suggestion. I will try it with another array creation script. But the main problem is solved with this. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you clear your array every iteration. Put your array declaration before the loop.

```
$pers_inventar = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                
    $pers_id = $row['pers_id'];
    $pers_person = array('birthday' => $row['pers_birthday'],'lastname' => $row['pers_lastname'],'firstname' => $row['pers_firstname'],'job' => $row['pers_job']);
    $pers_inventar[$pers_id][] = $pers_person;
}
```